# Accessing public folder in Sinatra Rackup

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra, rack, sinatra-activerecord

I have a small Sinatra app using rackup and Sinatra::Base (modular application). My views folder is accessible but my public folder which has style sheets and java script is not accessible at all when, I run my app using command `rerun rackup`. I have tried many things given on stack overflow but nothing could solve the problem

**controllers/applicatoin_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < Sinatra::Base
    set :views, Proc.new    {File.join(root, "../views/")}
    set :public_folder , Proc.new {File.join(root,"../public")}
    enable :static
end
```

**layout.erb**

```
<link rel="stylesheets" href="main.css">
```

**application folder structure**

```
.
|-- app.rb
|-- config
|   |-- database.yml 
|   `-- environment.rb
|-- config.ru
|-- controllers
|   |-- application_controller.rb
|   |-- ratings_controller.rb
|   |-- recipies_controller.rb
|   `-- users_controller.rb
|-- Gemfile
|-- Gemfile.lock
|-- helpers
|-- lib
|   `-- sinatra
|       `-- auth.rb
|-- models
|   |-- category.rb
|   |-- rating.rb
|   |-- recipie.rb
|   |-- sub_category.rb
|   |-- text.rb
|   `-- user.rb
|-- public
|   |-- images
|   |-- javascripts
|   |   |-- holder.min.js
|   |   `-- ratings.js
|   `-- stylesheets
|       `-- main.css
|-- rakefile.rb 
|
`-- views
|-- auth_layout.erb
|-- create_recipie.erb
|-- edit_recipie.erb
|-- index.erb
|-- layout.erb
|-- login.erb
|-- not_found.erb
|-- recipie.erb
|-- recipies.erb
`-- signup.erb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should prefix it with `stylesheets` : `href='stylesheets/main.css'`. It won't find and resolve static files recursively in the public directory.

Also `rel` attribute of you link tag should be `stylesheet` not `stylesheets`.